# run jboss in domain mode

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, application-server

I need to implement cluster mechanism in my application. while doing this I got an error while start the jbossAS7
Error is::

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/chandrashekar/CHE/SoftWares/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.domain.default.config=domain.xml -Djboss.host.default.config=host.xml

=========================================================================

19:18:52,599 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
19:18:52,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (main) JBAS012017: Starting process 'Host Controller'
[Host Controller] 19:18:53,082 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
[Host Controller] 19:18:53,196 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
[Host Controller] 19:18:53,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
[Host Controller] 19:18:54,070 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
[Host Controller]     ("host" => "master"),
[Host Controller]     ("interface" => "management")
[Host Controller] ]) - failure description: "JBAS014692: Invalid address ${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.9.252 (${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.9.252)"
[Host Controller] 19:18:54,098 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
[Host Controller] 19:18:54,110 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
[Host Controller] 19:18:54,130 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
[Host Controller] 19:18:54,327 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS014774: Service status report
[Host Controller] JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
[Host Controller]       service jboss.network.management (missing) dependents: [service jboss.host.controller.server-inventory] 
[Host Controller]
```

## My host.xml is::

```
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir" />
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        </native-interface>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
</management>

<domain-controller>
   <local/>
   <!-- Alternative remote domain controller configuration with a host and port -->
   <!-- <remote host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}"/> -->
</domain-controller>

<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.9.252"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
       <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.9.252}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <!-- Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
             To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL -->
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:192.168.9.252}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<jvms>
   <jvm name="default">
      <heap size="64m" max-size="256m"/>
      <permgen size="256m" max-size="256m"/>
        <jvm-options>
            <option value="-server"/>
        </jvm-options>
   </jvm>
</jvms>

<servers>
    <server name="server-one" group="main-server-group">
        <!-- Remote JPDA debugging for a specific server
        <jvm name="default">
          <jvm-options>
            <option value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"/>
          </jvm-options>
       </jvm>
       -->
    </server>
    <server name="server-two" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true">
        <!-- server-two avoids port conflicts by incrementing the ports in
             the default socket-group declared in the server-group -->
        <socket-bindings port-offset="150"/>
    </server>
    <server name="server-three" group="other-server-group" auto-start="false">
        <!-- server-three avoids port conflicts by incrementing the ports in
             the default socket-group declared in the server-group -->
        <socket-bindings port-offset="250"/>
    </server>
</servers>
```

can any on help me out please.

Comment: what about your domain.xml ? And of course Have you checked whether the 9.252 is available ! ! !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your first interface you're missing the trailing `}`.

You have:

```
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.9.252"/>
```

It should be:

```
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.9.252}"/>
```